# Adding up Total Distance traveled in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, geolocation

Using the geolocation plugin for apache cordova / phonegap

Originally from, [DaveAlden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013619/find-distance-speed-and-acceleration-using-geolocation-api-cordova-phonegap)  + Chris Veness

I'm simply trying to sum up the deltaDistMetres. Have been working at it all day but can't figure it out. Tried the push and reduce method with arrays, for loops, try troubleshooting with isNaN(). I'm at your mercy stack overflow pros.

My understanding of deltaDistMetres is the distance between the current gps location and the one before. So summing them up would be the total distance correct?
Thanks for any help!

```
var currentUpdate, lastUpdate;

function onPositionUpdate(position) {

    if (currentUpdate) lastUpdate = currentUpdate;

    currentUpdate = {
        position: new LatLon(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
        time: new Date()
    };

    if (!lastUpdate) return;

    currentUpdate.deltaDistMetres = lastUpdate.position.distanceTo(currentUpdate.position) * 1000;
    currentUpdate.deltaTimeSecs = (currentUpdate.time - lastUpdate.time) * 1000;
    currentUpdate.speed = (currentUpdate.deltaDistMetres / currentUpdate.deltaTimeSecs);
    currentUpdate.accelerationGPS = (currentUpdate.speed - lastUpdate.speed) / currentUpdate.deltaTimeSecs;


/* THIS IS MY LITTLE CODE 
(I have an element id="log" in my html)
*/

    var distanceTotal= 0;
    var distanceChange = currentUpdate.deltaDistMetres;
    distanceTotal += distanceChange;
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "Total distance " + distanceTotal + " m";

}
function onPositionError(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.message);
}

$(document).on("deviceready", function () {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onPositionUpdate, onPositionError, { frequency:3000, timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true });

});


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
/*  Latitude/longitude spherical geodesy formulae & scripts (c) Chris Veness 2002-2012            */
/*   - www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html                                                */
/*                                                                                                */
/*  Sample usage:                                                                                 */
/*    var p1 = new LatLon(51.5136, -0.0983);                                                      */
/*    var p2 = new LatLon(51.4778, -0.0015);                                                      */
/*    var dist = p1.distanceTo(p2);          // in km                                             */
/*    var brng = p1.bearingTo(p2);           // in degrees clockwise from north                   */
/*    ... etc                                                                                     */
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
/*  Note that minimal error checking is performed in this example code!                           */
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */


/**
 * Object LatLon: tools for geodetic calculations
 *
 * @requires Geo
 */


/**
 * Creates a point on the earth's surface at the supplied latitude / longitude
 *
 * @constructor
 * @param {Number} lat: latitude in degrees
 * @param {Number} lon: longitude in degrees
 * @param {Number} [radius=6371]: radius of earth if different value is required from standard 6,371km
 */
function LatLon(lat, lon, radius) {
    if (typeof (radius) == 'undefined') radius = 6371;  // earth's mean radius in km

    this.lat = Number(lat);
    this.lon = Number(lon);
    this.radius = Number(radius);
}


/**
 * Returns the distance from this point to the supplied point, in km 
 * (using Haversine formula)
 *
 * from: Haversine formula - R. W. Sinnott, "Virtues of the Haversine",
 *       Sky and Telescope, vol 68, no 2, 1984
 *
 * @this    {LatLon} latitude/longitude of origin point
 * @param   {LatLon} point: latitude/longitude of destination point
 * @param   {Number} [precision=4]: number of significant digits to use for returned value
 * @returns {Number} distance in km between this point and destination point
 */
LatLon.prototype.distanceTo = function (point, precision) {
    // default 4 sig figs reflects typical 0.3% accuracy of spherical model
    if (typeof precision == 'undefined') precision = 4;

    var R = this.radius;
    var φ1 = this.lat.toRadians(), λ1 = this.lon.toRadians();
    var φ2 = point.lat.toRadians(), λ2 = point.lon.toRadians();
    var Δφ = φ2 - φ1;
    var Δλ = λ2 - λ1;

    var a = Math.sin(Δφ / 2) * Math.sin(Δφ / 2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
        Math.sin(Δλ / 2) * Math.sin(Δλ / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c;

    return d.toPrecisionFixed(Number(precision));
}


/**
 * Returns the (initial) bearing from this point to the supplied point, in degrees
 *   see http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Crs
 *
 * @this    {LatLon} latitude/longitude of origin point
 * @param   {LatLon} point: latitude/longitude of destination point
 * @returns {Number} initial bearing in degrees from North
 */
LatLon.prototype.bearingTo = function (point) {
    var φ1 = this.lat.toRadians(), φ2 = point.lat.toRadians();
    var Δλ = (point.lon - this.lon).toRadians();

    var y = Math.sin(Δλ) * Math.cos(φ2);
    var x = Math.cos(φ1) * Math.sin(φ2) -
        Math.sin(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) * Math.cos(Δλ);
    var θ = Math.atan2(y, x);

    return (θ.toDegrees() + 360) % 360;
}


/**
 * Returns final bearing arriving at supplied destination point from this point; the final bearing 
 * will differ from the initial bearing by varying degrees according to distance and latitude
 *
 * @this    {LatLon} latitude/longitude of origin point
 * @param   {LatLon} point: latitude/longitude of destination point
 * @returns {Number} final bearing in degrees from North
 */
LatLon.prototype.finalBearingTo = function (point) {
    // get initial bearing from supplied point back to this point...
    var φ1 = point.lat.toRadians(), φ2 = this.lat.toRadians();
    var Δλ = (this.lon - point.lon).toRadians();

    var y = Math.sin(Δλ) * Math.cos(φ2);
    var x = Math.cos(φ1) * Math.sin(φ2) -
        Math.sin(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) * Math.cos(Δλ);
    var θ = Math.atan2(y, x);

    // ... & reverse it by adding 180°
    return (θ.toDegrees() + 180) % 360;
}


/**
 * Returns the midpoint between this point and the supplied point.
 *   see http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51822.html for derivation
 *
 * @this    {LatLon} latitude/longitude of origin point
 * @param   {LatLon} point: latitude/longitude of destination point
 * @returns {LatLon} midpoint between this point and the supplied point
 */
LatLon.prototype.midpointTo = function (point) {
    var φ1 = this.lat.toRadians(), λ1 = this.lon.toRadians();
    var φ2 = point.lat.toRadians();
    var Δλ = (point.lon - this.lon).toRadians();

    var Bx = Math.cos(φ2) * Math.cos(Δλ);
    var By = Math.cos(φ2) * Math.sin(Δλ);

    var φ3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(φ1) + Math.sin(φ2),
        Math.sqrt((Math.cos(φ1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(φ1) + Bx) + By * By));
    var λ3 = λ1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(φ1) + Bx);
    λ3 = (λ3 + 3 * Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI; // normalise to -180..+180º

    return new LatLon(φ3.toDegrees(), λ3.toDegrees());
}


/**
 * Returns the destination point from this point having travelled the given distance (in km) on the 
 * given initial bearing (bearing may vary before destination is reached)
 *
 *   see http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#LL
 *
 * @this    {LatLon} latitude/longitude of origin point
 * @param   {Number} brng: initial bearing in degrees
 * @param   {Number} dist: distance in km
 * @returns {LatLon} destination point
 */
LatLon.prototype.destinationPoint = function (brng, dist) {
    var θ = Number(brng).toRadians();
    var δ = Number(dist) / this.radius; // angular distance in radians

    var φ1 = this.lat.toRadians();
    var λ1 = this.lon.toRadians();

    var φ2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(φ1) * Math.cos(δ) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.sin(δ) * Math.cos(θ));
    var λ2 = λ1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(θ) * Math.sin(δ) * Math.cos(φ1),
        Math.cos(δ) - Math.sin(φ1) * Math.sin(φ2));
    λ2 = (λ2 + 3 * Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI; // normalise to -180..+180º

    return new LatLon(φ2.toDegrees(), λ2.toDegrees());
}


/**
 * Returns the point of intersection of two paths defined by point and bearing
 *
 *   see http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Intersection
 *
 * @param   {LatLon} p1: first point
 * @param   {Number} brng1: initial bearing from first point
 * @param   {LatLon} p2: second point
 * @param   {Number} brng2: initial bearing from second point
 * @returns {LatLon} destination point (null if no unique intersection defined)
 */
LatLon.intersection = function (p1, brng1, p2, brng2) {
    var φ1 = p1.lat.toRadians(), λ1 = p1.lon.toRadians();
    var φ2 = p2.lat.toRadians(), λ2 = p2.lon.toRadians();
    var θ13 = Number(brng1).toRadians(), θ23 = Number(brng2).toRadians();
    var Δφ = φ2 - φ1, Δλ = λ2 - λ1;

    var δ12 = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.sin(Δφ / 2) * Math.sin(Δφ / 2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) * Math.sin(Δλ / 2) * Math.sin(Δλ / 2)));
    if (δ12 == 0) return null;

    // initial/final bearings between points
    var θ1 = Math.acos((Math.sin(φ2) - Math.sin(φ1) * Math.cos(δ12)) /
        (Math.sin(δ12) * Math.cos(φ1)));
    if (isNaN(θ1)) θ1 = 0; // protect against rounding
    var θ2 = Math.acos((Math.sin(φ1) - Math.sin(φ2) * Math.cos(δ12)) /
        (Math.sin(δ12) * Math.cos(φ2)));

    if (Math.sin(λ2 - λ1) > 0) {
        θ12 = θ1;
        θ21 = 2 * Math.PI - θ2;
    } else {
        θ12 = 2 * Math.PI - θ1;
        θ21 = θ2;
    }

    var α1 = (θ13 - θ12 + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI; // angle 2-1-3
    var α2 = (θ21 - θ23 + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI; // angle 1-2-3

    if (Math.sin(α1) == 0 && Math.sin(α2) == 0) return null; // infinite intersections
    if (Math.sin(α1) * Math.sin(α2) < 0) return null;      // ambiguous intersection

    //α1 = Math.abs(α1);
    //α2 = Math.abs(α2);
    // ... Ed Williams takes abs of α1/α2, but seems to break calculation?

    var α3 = Math.acos(-Math.cos(α1) * Math.cos(α2) +
        Math.sin(α1) * Math.sin(α2) * Math.cos(δ12));
    var δ13 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(δ12) * Math.sin(α1) * Math.sin(α2),
        Math.cos(α2) + Math.cos(α1) * Math.cos(α3))
    var φ3 = Math.asin(Math.sin(φ1) * Math.cos(δ13) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.sin(δ13) * Math.cos(θ13));
    var Δλ13 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(θ13) * Math.sin(δ13) * Math.cos(φ1),
        Math.cos(δ13) - Math.sin(φ1) * Math.sin(φ3));
    var λ3 = λ1 + Δλ13;
    λ3 = (λ3 + 3 * Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI; // normalise to -180..+180º

    return new LatLon(φ3.toDegrees(), λ3.toDegrees());
}


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

/**
 * Returns the distance from this point to the supplied point, in km, travelling along a rhumb line
 *
 *   see http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Rhumb
 *
 * @this    {LatLon} latitude/longitude of origin point
 * @param   {LatLon} point: latitude/longitude of destination point
 * @returns {Number} distance in km between this point and destination point
 */
LatLon.prototype.rhumbDistanceTo = function (point) {
    var R = this.radius;
    var φ1 = this.lat.toRadians(), φ2 = point.lat.toRadians();
    var Δφ = φ2 - φ1;
    var Δλ = Math.abs(point.lon - this.lon).toRadians();
    // if dLon over 180° take shorter rhumb line across the anti-meridian:
    if (Math.abs(Δλ) > Math.PI) Δλ = Δλ > 0 ? -(2 * Math.PI - Δλ) : (2 * Math.PI + Δλ);

    // on Mercator projection, longitude gets increasing stretched by latitude; q is the 'stretch factor'

    var Δψ = Math.log(Math.tan(φ2 / 2 + Math.PI / 4) / Math.tan(φ1 / 2 + Math.PI / 4));

    // the stretch factor becomes ill-conditioned along E-W line (0/0); use empirical tolerance to avoid it
    var q = Math.abs(Δψ) > 10e-12 ? Δφ / Δψ : Math.cos(φ1);

    // distance is pythagoras on 'stretched' Mercator projection
    var δ = Math.sqrt(Δφ * Δφ + q * q * Δλ * Δλ); // angular distance in radians
    var dist = δ * R;

    return dist.toPrecisionFixed(4); // 4 sig figs reflects typical 0.3% accuracy of spherical model
}


/**
 * Returns the bearing from this point to the supplied point along a rhumb line, in degrees
 *
 * @this    {LatLon} latitude/longitude of origin point
 * @param   {LatLon} point: latitude/longitude of destination point
 * @returns {Number} bearing in degrees from North
 */
LatLon.prototype.rhumbBearingTo = function (point) {
    var φ1 = this.lat.toRadians(), φ2 = point.lat.toRadians();
    var Δλ = (point.lon - this.lon).toRadians();
    // if dLon over 180° take shorter rhumb line across the anti-meridian:
    if (Math.abs(Δλ) > Math.PI) Δλ = Δλ > 0 ? -(2 * Math.PI - Δλ) : (2 * Math.PI + Δλ);

    var Δψ = Math.log(Math.tan(φ2 / 2 + Math.PI / 4) / Math.tan(φ1 / 2 + Math.PI / 4));

    var θ = Math.atan2(Δλ, Δψ);

    return (θ.toDegrees() + 360) % 360;
}


/**
 * Returns the destination point from this point having travelled the given distance (in km) on the 
 * given bearing along a rhumb line
 *
 * @this    {LatLon} latitude/longitude of origin point
 * @param   {Number} brng: bearing in degrees from North
 * @param   {Number} dist: distance in km
 * @returns {LatLon} destination point
 */
LatLon.prototype.rhumbDestinationPoint = function (brng, dist) {
    var δ = Number(dist) / this.radius; // angular distance in radians
    var φ1 = this.lat.toRadians(), λ1 = this.lon.toRadians();
    var θ = Number(brng).toRadians();

    var Δφ = δ * Math.cos(θ);

    var φ2 = φ1 + Δφ;
    // check for some daft bugger going past the pole, normalise latitude if so
    if (Math.abs(φ2) > Math.PI / 2) φ2 = φ2 > 0 ? Math.PI - φ2 : -Math.PI - φ2;

    var Δψ = Math.log(Math.tan(φ2 / 2 + Math.PI / 4) / Math.tan(φ1 / 2 + Math.PI / 4));
    var q = Math.abs(Δψ) > 10e-12 ? Δφ / Δψ : Math.cos(φ1); // E-W course becomes ill-conditioned with 0/0

    var Δλ = δ * Math.sin(θ) / q;

    var λ2 = λ1 + Δλ;

    λ2 = (λ2 + 3 * Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI; // normalise to -180..+180º

    return new LatLon(φ2.toDegrees(), λ2.toDegrees());
}


/**
 * Returns the loxodromic midpoint (along a rhumb line) between this point and the supplied point.
 *   see http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=148837
 *
 * @this    {LatLon} latitude/longitude of origin point
 * @param   {LatLon} point: latitude/longitude of destination point
 * @returns {LatLon} midpoint between this point and the supplied point
 */
LatLon.prototype.rhumbMidpointTo = function (point) {
    var φ1 = this.lat.toRadians(), λ1 = this.lon.toRadians();
    var φ2 = point.lat.toRadians(), λ2 = point.lon.toRadians();

    if (Math.abs(λ2 - λ1) > Math.PI) λ1 += 2 * Math.PI; // crossing anti-meridian

    var φ3 = (φ1 + φ2) / 2;
    var f1 = Math.tan(Math.PI / 4 + φ1 / 2);
    var f2 = Math.tan(Math.PI / 4 + φ2 / 2);
    var f3 = Math.tan(Math.PI / 4 + φ3 / 2);
    var λ3 = ((λ2 - λ1) * Math.log(f3) + λ1 * Math.log(f2) - λ2 * Math.log(f1)) / Math.log(f2 / f1);

    if (!isFinite(λ3)) λ3 = (λ1 + λ2) / 2; // parallel of latitude

    λ3 = (λ3 + 3 * Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI; // normalise to -180..+180º

    return new LatLon(φ3.toDegrees(), λ3.toDegrees());
}


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */


/**
 * Returns a string representation of this point; format and dp as per lat()/lon()
 *
 * @this    {LatLon} latitude/longitude of origin point
 * @param   {String} [format]: return value as 'd', 'dm', 'dms'
 * @param   {Number} [dp=0|2|4]: number of decimal places to display
 * @returns {String} comma-separated latitude/longitude
 */
LatLon.prototype.toString = function (format, dp) {
    if (typeof format == 'undefined') format = 'dms';

    return Geo.toLat(this.lat, format, dp) + ', ' + Geo.toLon(this.lon, format, dp);
}


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */


// ---- extend Number object with methods for converting degrees/radians


/** Converts numeric degrees to radians */
if (typeof Number.prototype.toRadians == 'undefined') {
    Number.prototype.toRadians = function () {
        return this * Math.PI / 180;
    }
}


/** Converts radians to numeric (signed) degrees */
if (typeof Number.prototype.toDegrees == 'undefined') {
    Number.prototype.toDegrees = function () {
        return this * 180 / Math.PI;
    }
}


/** 
 * Formats the significant digits of a number, using only fixed-point notation (no exponential)
 * 
 * @param   {Number} precision: Number of significant digits to appear in the returned string
 * @returns {String} A string representation of number which contains precision significant digits
 */
if (typeof Number.prototype.toPrecisionFixed == 'undefined') {
    Number.prototype.toPrecisionFixed = function (precision) {

        // use standard toPrecision method
        var n = this.toPrecision(precision);

        // ... but replace +ve exponential format with trailing zeros
        n = n.replace(/(.+)e\+(.+)/, function (n, sig, exp) {
            sig = sig.replace(/\./, '');       // remove decimal from significand
            l = sig.length - 1;
            while (exp-- > l) sig = sig + '0'; // append zeros from exponent
            return sig;
        });

        // ... and replace -ve exponential format with leading zeros
        n = n.replace(/(.+)e-(.+)/, function (n, sig, exp) {
            sig = sig.replace(/\./, '');       // remove decimal from significand
            while (exp-- > 1) sig = '0' + sig; // prepend zeros from exponent
            return '0.' + sig;
        });

        return n;
    }
}


/** Trims whitespace from string (q.v. blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript) */
if (typeof String.prototype.trim == 'undefined') {
    String.prototype.trim = function () {
        return String(this).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    }
}


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
if (!window.console) window.console = { log: function () { } };
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
/*  Geodesy representation conversion functions (c) Chris Veness 2002-2012                        */
/*   - www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html                                                */
/*                                                                                                */
/*  Sample usage:                                                                                 */
/*    var lat = Geo.parseDMS('51° 28′ 40.12″ N');                                                 */
/*    var lon = Geo.parseDMS('000° 00′ 05.31″ W');                                                */
/*    var p1 = new LatLon(lat, lon);                                                              */
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */


var Geo = {};  // Geo namespace, representing static class


/**
 * Parses string representing degrees/minutes/seconds into numeric degrees
 *
 * This is very flexible on formats, allowing signed decimal degrees, or deg-min-sec optionally
 * suffixed by compass direction (NSEW). A variety of separators are accepted (eg 3º 37' 09"W) 
 * or fixed-width format without separators (eg 0033709W). Seconds and minutes may be omitted. 
 * (Note minimal validation is done).
 *
 * @param   {String|Number} dmsStr: Degrees or deg/min/sec in variety of formats
 * @returns {Number} Degrees as decimal number
 * @throws  {TypeError} dmsStr is an object, perhaps DOM object without .value?
 */
Geo.parseDMS = function (dmsStr) {
    if (typeof deg == 'object') throw new TypeError('Geo.parseDMS - dmsStr is [DOM?] object');

    // check for signed decimal degrees without NSEW, if so return it directly
    if (typeof dmsStr === 'number' && isFinite(dmsStr)) return Number(dmsStr);

    // strip off any sign or compass dir'n & split out separate d/m/s
    var dms = String(dmsStr).trim().replace(/^-/, '').replace(/[NSEW]$/i, '').split(/[^0-9.,]+/);
    if (dms[dms.length - 1] == '') dms.splice(dms.length - 1);  // from trailing symbol

    if (dms == '') return NaN;

    // and convert to decimal degrees...
    switch (dms.length) {
        case 3:  // interpret 3-part result as d/m/s
            var deg = dms[0] / 1 + dms[1] / 60 + dms[2] / 3600;
            break;
        case 2:  // interpret 2-part result as d/m
            var deg = dms[0] / 1 + dms[1] / 60;
            break;
        case 1:  // just d (possibly decimal) or non-separated dddmmss
            var deg = dms[0];
            // check for fixed-width unseparated format eg 0033709W
            //if (/[NS]/i.test(dmsStr)) deg = '0' + deg;  // - normalise N/S to 3-digit degrees
            //if (/[0-9]{7}/.test(deg)) deg = deg.slice(0,3)/1 + deg.slice(3,5)/60 + deg.slice(5)/3600; 
            break;
        default:
            return NaN;
    }
    if (/^-|[WS]$/i.test(dmsStr.trim())) deg = -deg; // take '-', west and south as -ve
    return Number(deg);
}


/**
 * Convert decimal degrees to deg/min/sec format
 *  - degree, prime, double-prime symbols are added, but sign is discarded, though no compass
 *    direction is added
 *
 * @private
 * @param   {Number} deg: Degrees
 * @param   {String} [format=dms]: Return value as 'd', 'dm', 'dms'
 * @param   {Number} [dp=0|2|4]: No of decimal places to use - default 0 for dms, 2 for dm, 4 for d
 * @returns {String} deg formatted as deg/min/secs according to specified format
 * @throws  {TypeError} deg is an object, perhaps DOM object without .value?
 */
Geo.toDMS = function (deg, format, dp) {
    if (typeof deg == 'object') throw new TypeError('Geo.toDMS - deg is [DOM?] object');
    if (isNaN(deg)) return null;  // give up here if we can't make a number from deg

    // default values
    if (typeof format == 'undefined') format = 'dms';
    if (typeof dp == 'undefined') {
        switch (format) {
            case 'd': dp = 4; break;
            case 'dm': dp = 2; break;
            case 'dms': dp = 0; break;
            default: format = 'dms'; dp = 0;  // be forgiving on invalid format
        }
    }

    deg = Math.abs(deg);  // (unsigned result ready for appending compass dir'n)

    switch (format) {
        case 'd':
            d = deg.toFixed(dp);     // round degrees
            if (d < 100) d = '0' + d;  // pad with leading zeros
            if (d < 10) d = '0' + d;
            dms = d + '\u00B0';      // add º symbol
            break;
        case 'dm':
            var min = (deg * 60).toFixed(dp);  // convert degrees to minutes & round
            var d = Math.floor(min / 60);    // get component deg/min
            var m = (min % 60).toFixed(dp);  // pad with trailing zeros
            if (d < 100) d = '0' + d;          // pad with leading zeros
            if (d < 10) d = '0' + d;
            if (m < 10) m = '0' + m;
            dms = d + '\u00B0' + m + '\u2032';  // add º, ' symbols
            break;
        case 'dms':
            var sec = (deg * 3600).toFixed(dp);  // convert degrees to seconds & round
            var d = Math.floor(sec / 3600);    // get component deg/min/sec
            var m = Math.floor(sec / 60) % 60;
            var s = (sec % 60).toFixed(dp);    // pad with trailing zeros
            if (d < 100) d = '0' + d;            // pad with leading zeros
            if (d < 10) d = '0' + d;
            if (m < 10) m = '0' + m;
            if (s < 10) s = '0' + s;
            dms = d + '\u00B0' + m + '\u2032' + s + '\u2033';  // add º, ', " symbols
            break;
    }

    return dms;
}


/**
 * Convert numeric degrees to deg/min/sec latitude (suffixed with N/S)
 *
 * @param   {Number} deg: Degrees
 * @param   {String} [format=dms]: Return value as 'd', 'dm', 'dms'
 * @param   {Number} [dp=0|2|4]: No of decimal places to use - default 0 for dms, 2 for dm, 4 for d
 * @returns {String} Deg/min/seconds
 */
Geo.toLat = function (deg, format, dp) {
    var lat = Geo.toDMS(deg, format, dp);
    return lat == null ? '–' : lat.slice(1) + (deg < 0 ? 'S' : 'N');  // knock off initial '0' for lat!
}


/**
 * Convert numeric degrees to deg/min/sec longitude (suffixed with E/W)
 *
 * @param   {Number} deg: Degrees
 * @param   {String} [format=dms]: Return value as 'd', 'dm', 'dms'
 * @param   {Number} [dp=0|2|4]: No of decimal places to use - default 0 for dms, 2 for dm, 4 for d
 * @returns {String} Deg/min/seconds
 */
Geo.toLon = function (deg, format, dp) {
    var lon = Geo.toDMS(deg, format, dp);
    return lon == null ? '–' : lon + (deg < 0 ? 'W' : 'E');
}


/**
 * Convert numeric degrees to deg/min/sec as a bearing (0º..360º)
 *
 * @param   {Number} deg: Degrees
 * @param   {String} [format=dms]: Return value as 'd', 'dm', 'dms'
 * @param   {Number} [dp=0|2|4]: No of decimal places to use - default 0 for dms, 2 for dm, 4 for d
 * @returns {String} Deg/min/seconds
 */
Geo.toBrng = function (deg, format, dp) {
    deg = (Number(deg) + 360) % 360;  // normalise -ve values to 180º..360º
    var brng = Geo.toDMS(deg, format, dp);
    return brng == null ? '–' : brng.replace('360', '0');  // just in case rounding took us up to 360º!
}


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
if (!window.console) window.console = { log: function () { } };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have placed the declaration `var distanceTotal= 0;` inside `onPositionUpdate()` which means it will be reset to zero on every position update. 
To preserve the previous value, declare it outside of `onPositionUpdate`:

```
var currentUpdate, lastUpdate;
var distanceTotal= 0;

function onPositionUpdate(position) {

    if (currentUpdate) lastUpdate = currentUpdate;

    currentUpdate = {
        position: new LatLon(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
        time: new Date()
    };

    if (!lastUpdate) return;

    currentUpdate.deltaDistMetres = lastUpdate.position.distanceTo(currentUpdate.position) * 1000;
    currentUpdate.deltaTimeSecs = (currentUpdate.time - lastUpdate.time) * 1000;
    currentUpdate.speed = (currentUpdate.deltaDistMetres / currentUpdate.deltaTimeSecs);
    currentUpdate.accelerationGPS = (currentUpdate.speed - lastUpdate.speed) / currentUpdate.deltaTimeSecs;


/* THIS IS MY LITTLE CODE 
(I have an element id="log" in my html)
*/
    var distanceChange = currentUpdate.deltaDistMetres;
    distanceTotal += distanceChange;
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "Total distance " + distanceTotal + " m";

}
function onPositionError(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.message);
}

$(document).on("deviceready", function () {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onPositionUpdate, onPositionError, { frequency:3000, timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true });

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I eventually figured it out. The next problem was it was adding up all the small deltadistances when I was standing still.  So I added if (currentUpdate.deltaDistMetres <=1.25) { currentUpdate.deltaDistMetres=0;} and it all seems to be working! Thanks for all your contributions DaveAlden!